# EaselJS - Several fonts

Tags: easeljs

I'm attempting to use more than 2 (actually 3) different font families using EaselJS and for some reason it's only rendering 2. Has anybody had a similar problem?

Javascript with EasleJs:

function init() {

```
 stage = new createjs.Stage("mycanvas");
 stage.enableMouseOver(10);
 stage.mouseMoveOutside = true;

 stage.mouseEventsEnabled = true;

 stage.snapToPixelEnabled = true;

 createjs.Touch.enable(stage);


 createjs.Ticker.setFPS(20);
 createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);

 handleResize();

 var txt = new createjs.Text();
 txt.x = txt.y = 0;
 txt.font = "56px QuicksandRegular";
 txt.color = "#EEEEEE";
 txt.text = "Hello World!";
 stage.addChild(txt);

 var txt1 = new createjs.Text();
 txt1.x = txt1.y = 200;
 txt1.font = "56px Hero";
 txt1.color = "#EEEEEE";
 txt1.text = "Hello World!";
 stage.addChild(txt1);


 var txt2 = new createjs.Text();
 txt2.x = txt2.y = 400;
 txt2.font = "56px LatinMono";
 txt2.color = "#EEEEEE";
 txt2.text = "Hello World!";
 stage.addChild(txt2);


 stage.update();    

}
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Hero";
src: url(../fonts/Hero.otf) format("opentype");

font-family: "QuicksandRegular";
src: url(../fonts/Quicksand-Regular.otf) format("opentype");

font-family: "LatinMono";
src: url(../fonts/lmmonolt10-regular.otf) format("opentype");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no CSS-expert, but I think you'll have to use an own `@font-face { ... }` for each font.
Maybe that solves your problem.

Comment: It worked! Clearly I'll have to my CSS homework. Thank you very much for your help.